# How to avoid longtable caption repetition in list of tables?

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

In the below MWE, the caption was repeated twice in the list of tables. How to make appear only once?

```
\documentclass[oneside,toc=graduated]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\newpage
\begin{longtable}{r r r r r r}
\caption[List of tables caption.]{Here is the caption beside the table with long text.}\label{tab:addlabel} \\
\toprule
Time & MAD & Group & Par1 & Par2 & Par3 \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
0     & 10.839 & 0     & 111.5 & 109.6 & 89.3  \\
200   & 10.854 & 0     & 111.6 & 109.6 & 89.3  \\
400   & 10.869 & 0     & 111.7 & 109.8 & 89.3  \\
600   & 10.898 & 0     & 111.8 & 109.9 & 89.3  \\
799   & 10.903 & 0     & 111.9 & 109.9 & 89.3  \\
0     & 10.916 & 0     & 112.1 & 110.1 & 89.5  \\
200   & 10.901 & 0     & 112.2 & 110.2 & 89.5  \\
400   & 10.569 & 0     & 112.4 & 110.4 & 89.5  \\
600   & 7.6   & 0     & 112.4 & 110.4 & 89.7  \\
799   & 4.861 & 0     & 112.5 & 110.4 & 90.6  \\
0     & 2.984 & 0     & 112.4 & 110.5 & 91.3  \\
200   & 0.74  & 0     & 112.3 & 110.3 & 91.1  \\
400   & 0.378 & 0     & 111.5 & 109.6 & 90.7  \\
600   & 0.391 & 0     & 111.7 & 109.6 & 90.9  \\
799   & 0.344 & 0     & 111.6 & 109.9 & 91.1  \\
0     & 0.388 & 0     & 111.9 & 110   & 91.6  \\
200   & 0.381 & 0     & 112.5 & 110.2 & 92    \\
400   & 0.366 & 0     & 112.6 & 110.4 & 92.6  \\
600   & 0.336 & 0     & 112.9 & 110.7 & 93    \\
799   & 0.328 & 0     & 113.1 & 110.9 & 93.6  \\
0     & 0.329 & 0     & 113.2 & 111.2 & 94.1  \\
200   & 0.393 & 0     & 113.4 & 111.4 & 95    \\
400   & 0.362 & 0     & 113.6 & 111.6 & 95.6  \\
600   & 0.345 & 0     & 113.8 & 111.9 & 96.3  \\
799   & 0.343 & 0     & 113.9 & 112.1 & 80    \\
0     & 0.335 & 0     & 113.9 & 112.4 & 97.6  \\
200   & 0.374 & 0     & 113.2 & 112.6 & 98.3  \\
400   & 0.403 & 0     & 114.6 & 112.9 & 98.9  \\
600   & 0.381 & 0     & 114.4 & 113.3 & 99.4  \\
799   & 0.388 & 0     & 115   & 113.7 & 100.1 \\
0     & 0.387 & 0     & 114.7 & 114.2 & 100.8 \\
200   & 0.41  & 0     & 115.3 & 115   & 101.9 \\
400   & 0.41  & 0     & 116.5 & 116.3 & 101.8 \\
600   & 0.421 & 0     & 117.5 & 118.6 & 102.3 \\
799   & 0.431 & 0     & 119.9 & 123.6 & 102.7 \\
0     & 0.442 & 0     & 125.3 & 132   & 103.3 \\
200   & 0.448 & 0     & 135.8 & 141.5 & 103.8 \\
400   & 0.465 & 0     & 151.1 & 147.4 & 104.4 \\
600   & 0.485 & 0     & 164.4 & 155.3 & 105.3 \\
799   & 0.495 & 0     & 181.1 & 175.6 & 106.4 \\
0     & 0.55  & 0     & 216.6 & 196.5 & 107.8 \\
200   & 0.561 & 0     & 246.8 & 215.1 & 108.1 \\
400   & 0.604 & 0     & 278   & 244   & 174.5 \\
600   & 0.646 & 0     & 304.2 & 273.1 & 174.1 \\
799   & 0.725 & 0     & 326.1 & 284.4 & 173.4 \\
0     & 0.759 & 0     & 337.3 & 293.5 & 172.5 \\
200   & 0.837 & 0     & 340.7 & 301.8 & 171.8 \\
400   & 0.864 & 0     & 342.3 & 306.3 & 170.6 \\
600   & 0.701 & 0     & 345.4 & 309.7 & 169.7 \\
799   & 0.876 & 0     & 346.2 & 307.6 & 169.1 \\
0     & 0.886 & 0     & 343.7 & 306.2 & 168.6 \\
200   & 0.876 & 0     & 340.9 & 305.4 & 168   \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**
The below lines of code now works based on Mico answer:

```
\documentclass[oneside,toc=graduated]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\newpage
\begin{longtable}{r r r r r r}
\caption[List of tables caption.]{Here is the caption beside the table with long text.\label{tab:addlabel}} \\
\toprule
Time & MAD\footnote{a} & Group\footnote{b} & Par1 & Par2 & Par3 \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Time & MAD\footnote{a} & Group\footnote{b} & Par1 & Par2 & Par3 \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\footnotetext{Median Absolute Deviation}
\footnotetext{Second footnote}
0     & 10.839 & 0     & 111.5 & 109.6 & 89.3  \\
200   & 10.854 & 0     & 111.6 & 109.6 & 89.3  \\
400   & 10.869 & 0     & 111.7 & 109.8 & 89.3  \\
<...truncated...>
600   & 0.701 & 0     & 345.4 & 309.7 & 169.7 \\
799   & 0.876 & 0     & 346.2 & 307.6 & 169.1 \\
0     & 0.886 & 0     & 343.7 & 306.2 & 168.6 \\
200   & 0.876 & 0     & 340.9 & 305.4 & 168   \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Read the documentation of longtable.

Comment: the only text relevant to the question was on page 8 of the manual, but no help.

Comment: The relevant text is on page 5. Around the sentence "... If the optional argument to \caption is empty, no entry is made in the list of tables..."

Comment: it seems that we are not on the same page, the one you mentioned is on page 4 in the manual I have 2004/02/01. But, either way that won't be helpful. The question is how to avoid repetition and has been answered. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide separate sets of code for the header of the *first page* of a longtable and for the header of the *subsequent pages*. Something like the following should work for you:

```
\begin{longtable}{r r r r r r}
\caption[List of tables caption.]{Here is the caption beside the table with long text.}\label{tab:addlabel} \\
\toprule
Time & MAD & Group & Par1 & Par2 & Par3 \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Time & MAD & Group & Par1 & Par2 & Par3 \\
\midrule
\endhead
...
```

Note that the code for `\endhead` is the same as for `\endfirsthead` except for the omitted `\caption[]{}` line.

Comment: I missed that, now question updated with the answer.

Comment: @doctorate - A minor point in the grand scheme of things, but of some relevance nevertheless: Since you're loading the `booktabs` package anyway, you may want to use `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` rather than the basic LaTeX `\hline` command.